# My android application don't retrieve data when my phone is on Wifi

Tags: android, json, wifi

I have a nexus 5 and I develop an Android Application on this.

Since the launch of the devlopment, my phone is connect by 4G or 3G. But, when I connect this to Wi-fi, the application don't retrieve data for a WEB API JSON.

I have this permissions in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I try my connection with this code :

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Une connexion internet est requise", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

If wi-fi and 3G are enabled : not Toast
If wi-fi is enable and 3G disable : not Toast
If wi-fi and 3G are disabled : Toast

The data are retrieve since a WEB API JSON and are download via a AsyncTask.

Don't hesitate if you want additional info or code.

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: "If wi-fi and 3G are enabled : not Toast If wi-fi is enable and 3G disable : not Toast If wi-fi and 3G are disabled : Toast"
so what is wrong ?

Comment: The problem is that the data aren't retrieve. Also I think my appli don't connect to internet via Wi-fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for check connection use this code

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String status = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = "Wifi enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = "Mobile data enabled";
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = "Not connected to Internet";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

and call

```
if(NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(getApplicationContext()).equals("Not connected to Internet"))
            {

                 alert();
        }
        else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your checking only for one network connection, get all network connection and check.
Replace your network info line with this code

**

> NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

**

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I try your code with Log.d

This is the LogCat when Wi-fi and 3G are enable :

networkInfo3G: NetworkInfo: type: mobile[LTE], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: dataDisabled, extra: ****.com, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false
AND
networkInfoWi-fi: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "****", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false